# GraphViz: Parent with only left child or only right child

Tags: graphviz

Is there a way to draw the tree that only points to the left or points to the right? I am trying to draw a binary search tree. Sometimes a parent only have left child or right child.

If there is only one child, by default, the child branch will go straight down. i wanted it to branch out to left/right.

Also, if a node have two children, by default, the first one will be the left child, but sometimes the tree only has right child, so is there a way to get around it and create the right child without create a left child with "NULL" value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this?  It's not a NULL child on the other side, but it is invisible.  Invisible center nodes help balance the tree.

```
graph binary {
root -- A1
root -- B1
A11 [style=invis]
A1 -- A11 [style=invis];
A1Center [style=invis, width=0, label=""];
A1 -- A1Center [style=invis];
A1 -- A12 ;
{rank=same A11 -- A1Center -- A12 [style=invis] }

B1 -- B11 ;
B1Center [style=invis, width=0, label=""];
B1 -- B1Center [style=invis];
B1 -- B12 ;
{rank=same B11 -- B1Center -- B12 [style=invis] }
}
```

[image]

Comment: @FyrZheng  You're quite welcome!  Glad to be able to help. :)