# Graphviz Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, pygraphviz

quick question, is there a way to display a tree is more bst manner, instead of standard graph one?[image]

Comment: Please see my older answer for a similar situation and feel free to upvote it if it suits your purpose:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45489390/graphviz-parent-with-only-left-child-or-only-right-child/45491566#45491566

Comment: please include your Graphviz source.